# SageMaker example access denied

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I am running the [k-means example in SageMaker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ex1-train-model-create-training-job.html):

```py
from sagemaker import KMeans

data_location = 's3://{}/kmeans_highlevel_example/data'.format(bucket)
output_location = 's3://{}/kmeans_example/output'.format(bucket)

kmeans = KMeans(role=role, 
                train_instance_count=2,
                train_instance_type='ml.c4.8xlarge',
                output_path=output_location,
                k=10, 
                data_location=data_location)
```

When I run this line, it appears access denied error.

```
%%time

kmeans.fit(kmeans.record_set(train_set[0]))
```

The error returns:

> ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the
> PutObject operation: Access Denied

I also read other questions, but their answers do not solve my problem.
Would you please look at my case?

Answer (score 4):

To be able to training a job in SageMaker, you need to pass in an **AWS IAM role** allowing SageMaker to access your S3 bucket.

The error means that SageMaker does not have permissions to write files in the bucket that you specified.

You can find the permissions that you need to add to your role hereL https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-roles.html#sagemaker-roles-createtrainingjob-perms

[sagemaker](/questions/tagged/sagemaker) [aws-sagemaker](/questions/tagged/aws-sagemaker) [role](/questions/tagged/role)

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem. My **Sagemaker Notebook Instance** wasn't able to read or write files to my S3 bucket. First step of troubleshooting is locating the role for your **Sagemaker Instance **. You can do that by checking this section [image: This is the information about your sagemaker instance]

Then go to this specific role from IAM and attach another policy to the role
[image: This is under roles in IAM]

I attached S3 Full access but you can create a custom policy.
I was getting confused because I was logged in using the admin user. However, when you go with a Sagemaker Instance your user policies/roles will not be used to perform actions.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to consider, if you are using an encrypted bucket, that requires kms decryption, make sure to also include kms related permissions
I've noticed sometimes the error shown is `PutObject operation: Access Denied` while failure is actually KMS related.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had just forgotten to rename the s3 bucket name from the default given to something that is unique